# How to add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object in perticular position?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

```
var obj = {key1: value1, key3: value3};
```

How can I insert new key value pairs `{key2: value2}` in second position of the object?

Comment: Objects don't retain order

Comment: (Not a precise duplicate, but the answer is effectively the same...)

Comment: @JoeClay I agree it's a duplicate. The answer is indeed the same - "no, you can't do this".

Comment: `Object.assign(obj, {key2:value2})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Objects`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) retain order, but it is not an index based form of data storage (getting the 'n-th' element may work, however the index 'n-th' does not always relate directly to the data).

You want to use an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) if you wish to retain order, or rather, define an index as a value pair within the object:

```
var obj = {
  key1: {index: 1, content: contentValue},
  key3: {index: 2, content: contentValue}
};
```

Comment: Name one Javascript implementation that doesn't retain order.

Comment: Objects retain order, however using the order of the object elements is not a good idea because they're not an order-based form of data storage. Arrays on the other hand are formed on order, using the element's position within the array as the key.

Comment: @John I clarified my answer. Of course objects retain order, but you *shouldn't* use that order for data manipulation.